# Represent a Java type as a varargs

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Is it possible to do something like this using Java features?

```
class myClass {int i; String s;}

static void myMethod(myClass... args)
{
...
}

main()
{
   myMethod(2,"two",3,"three");
}
```

Comment: Your method declaration is fine, but your method call in main is not. You are trying to use some kind of pseudo JSON-like notation.

Comment: @MisterSmith I guess that pseudo JSON-like notation was what the question was about. :-)

Comment: sometimes I just wait for a better answer, that never comes. situation solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible. Perhaps you could create a static helper method which makes creating your objects as easy as possible.

```
static myClass mc(int i, String s) {
    return new myClass(i, s);
}

myMethod(mc(2, "two"), mc(3, "three"));
```

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can make a constructor of `MyClass` and invoke:

```
myMethod(new MyClass(2, "two"), new Myclass(3, "three"));
```

For the sake of brevity you can make a statically-imported factory method:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass create(String s, int i) {
        return new MyClass(s, i);
    }
}
```

and use:

```
myMethod(create(2, "two"), create(3, "three"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a wrapper class:

```
class MyWrapper {
    private int i;
    private String s;

    public MyWrapper(int _i, String _s) {
        i = _i;
        s = _s;
    }
}

class Test {
    static void myMethod(MyWrapper... args) {
        //do work
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myMethod(new MyWrapper(2, "two"), new MyWrapper(3, "three"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sortof. You need a constructor of your class...

```
public class MyClass{
   int i
   String s;

   public MyClass(int i, String s){
      this.i = i;
      this.s = s;
   }
}

public static void myMethod(MyClass... instances){
     .....
}

public static void myMethod(Object... args){

    MyClass[] instances = new MyClass[args.length / 2];
    for (int i=0; i<args.length / 2; i++){
         instances[i] = new MyClass((Integer)args[i * 2], (String)args[(i*2) + 1]);
    }

    myMethod(instances);
}
```

You would need to add error checking to ensure that args has an even number of elements and there is not a method to enforce that every **i * 2** element is an Integer and every **i * 2 + 1** is a String. But it is possible.

Given all of the above, I will say... this is very non-standard programming and I would not recommend it. But as you see, it is possible.